# How to select elements from a set that are children of another element

Tags: jquery

The title is a bit confusing but here's what I'm after:

- I have a set of elements containing all the `h3` elements in a page.
  In jQuery terms: `var mySet = $('h3')`.
- I also have an div element `var myContainer = $('div#foo')`
- I need to find all items in the set `mySet` that are children of `myContainer`.

Any ideas? I bet there's some magical one liner for this but I cannot think of any. I'd rather *not* loop through every element in the set manually and use `.closest(myContainer)` or something like that to determine the relationship.

Note that in my scenario, I cannot use a new selector like `$('div#foo h3')` (that would be too easy) as I don't have access to the actual selector values. So it has to be dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. Assuming you have two jQuery collections and you **don't know the selectors**:

```
var myContainer = $('div');
var mySet = $('h3:even');
```

`filter` seems to work:

```
myContainer.children().filter(mySet)
```

Keep in mind, however, that this is **[undocumented](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** as far as I can see, so it may change.
[`.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) can also accept a collection of elements, which works similarly.

Working example: http://jsbin.com/owuru

Comment: As would this loop through myContainer.children, and compare each one to (worst case) each of mySet.

Comment: @unomi - this is essentially intersecting two sets, so yes, you have to go through both. In terms of complexity, it could be done in `nlogn`, and this is probably `n²`. Note that I did not assume there's a single parent.

Comment: All I meant with my answer is that it is possible that the initial selector is actually available, as Andy E confirmed - but as you later stated it is possible that they are not necessarily 'pure' selector generated lists, it renders my suggestion moot. If performance is a concern you should likely ensure that smallset.filter(largeset) and optionally remove hits from the largeset.

Comment: @Kobi I am not quite sure what you meant by "Note that I did not assume there's a single parent."

Comment: Sorry, I meant that `myContainer` may have more than a single element, "parent" is the wrong word here. I also use `.children` as a helper - My answer is really about intersecting two sets, which starts one step after `.children` was called. I see it as `var set1 = $('selector1'); var set2 = $('#id').children(); var result = set2.filter(set1);`

Comment: Thanks, this worked fine for me and filled my criteria :) Even though this is undocumented, it seems to work in the current jQuery version which is fine by me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to reduce the elements to those that match a specific selector:

```
mySet.filter("div#foo > *");
```

You can also get the selector used in a jQuery object by accessing the [.selector](http://api.jquery.com/selector/) property.

Comment: You don't always have a selector, you might have a collection: `$('div > :hidden').add('p').filter(':odd')` - I doubt you'll get a correct selector there, though I haven't checked.

Comment: Just a note, filter would exactly loop through all the elements of (in this case) mySet, albeit not _manually_.

Comment: @unomi: Very few jQuery selectors and DOM traversal methods are free of loops. The ones that don't involve loops are the ones that can attain the elements using `querySelectorAll()`, which isn't supported in older browsers. The point is that `.filter()` handles the looping *and* the condition checking for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about jQuery but in YUI3 nodelists returned from a selector query contain the actual selector string used to create the list, perhaps jquery exposes similar functionality?

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. The question explicitly asked to not loop through the sets. I am not sure if it is worth making the distinction of a forEach vs filter...